# Is there a better way targeting the last element child of previous sibling

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-objects

I mean the code does work, but at some point, it seems a bit weird to me, so I was wondering if someone does know a better way of targeting the last element child of the previous element sibling.

Basically, I have a slider which value I want to show with the span of its previous sibling, example:

```html
<div class="xOffsetBox">
  <label for="xOffset" class="xOffsetText">xOffset <span>0 px</span></label>
  <input type="range" name="xOffset" id="xOffsetRange1" min="-100" max="100" value="0">
</div>
```

And, within a js function, I get the value of the range input.

```
function getRangeValue () {

for (let i = 0; i < Shadows.length; i++) {
 let xOffset = document.getElementById(Shadows[i].xOffsetValue).value;
 let xOffsetSpan = document.getElementById(Shadows[i].xOffsetValue).previousElementSibling.lastElementChild;
 xOffsetSpan.textContent = xOffset + " px";
};
    };
```

Comment: Well when it is a previous sibling, there is not much you can do. If you give it a common class you could use DOM methods to get it from the parent, either way you are walking the tree.

Comment: The `label` element's `for` attribute should have a value that is equal to the `id` of the element it is labeling. Otherwise, it is labeling some other element. If it was properly labeling its element, you could use the [`labels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/labels) property of the element to get the `label`, then use `querySelector('span')` to get the `span` under that. Is that "better"; only you can say that.

Comment: Thank you guys for your support 

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use data-attributes they are quite useful. They don't pollute your css-class-attribute and it is not unique like id. Also, it is fairly easy to scale up.

There is not much you can do here with your query, since you try to work with a sibling.

The question is also: What are you trying to achieve here? What is "better" in your own words? Is it the lines of code, you want to reduce, reduce the complexity, or to find an alternative way? You could use an `id`, a `class`, or even a `data-attribute` on that sibling and just access it with `document.querySelector` or for id-lookup: `document.getElementById`. It really depends on what you try to accomplish.

You could, maybe, optimize it like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Shadows.length; i++) {
  const el = document.getElementById(Shadows[i].xOffsetValue);
  const xOffset = el.value;
  const xOffsetSpan = el.previousElementSibling.lastElementChild;
  xOffsetSpan.textContent = xOffset + " px";
};
```

This way you don't have to travel the `DOM` twice to find the element. You can also use `const` instead of `let`, if you don't want to modify these values.
Maybe even use a `for-of` iterator instead, if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my point I just didn't want to spam my html with automatically generate Id's to make it at some point easier to target the span. So I thought about targeting a sibling element to set the textContent. But what has been weird to me is, that I am kinda used to document.getAnything... for targeting something, and the way I did choose seemed to me like a roundabout way. You know what I mean? But still thanks for your support 

Comment: Well normally just add either a class or a data-attribute for the selection. This works good in tandem with styling the component. If this will always be a span you could write something akin to document.querySelector('.xOffsetText span') this would target the first node with the class xOffsetText applied and then select the first span-element inside of it. QuerySelector is similar to a css-rule.